# Compare table with spaces in between data, with table without spaces

Tags: sql

Compare table with spaces in between data, with table without spaces.

Data from table A is populated to Table B. I need to write MINUS query as Table A as Source, and table B as target

Sample data in table A, and table B:-

Table A has three fields: ID, Cd_1, and Cd_2

Fields: Cd_1 or Cd_2 can have spaces between the codes. Below example has two spaces between X and Y in Code_1

```
ID  | Cd_1    | Cd_2
-----------
1   | X  Y    | Z
```

Table B has two fields:  ID, Cd

Table B is supposed to populate codes (non-spaces) from Cd_1, and Cd_2 from Table A

Example:

```
ID | Cd
--------
1 | X    
1 | Y    
1 | Z
```

Comment: just a general comment .... whenever you find yourselves needing to do these sort of things (String splitting) ... it generally means that you have a poorly designed DB and that any solution that you come up with is only a band-aid.

Comment: Is your question actually something like that you want to check whether all values of table B are in table A?

Answer (score 0):

There is a table function use to split string based on a delimiter (space = ' ').

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT 
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
```

So to insert code from table A to table B you can use this query :

```
DECLARE @st1 as varchar(max),@st2 as varchar(max), @PractitionerId int

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT distinct  ID
FROM [dbo].[TableA]

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @PractitionerId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    select @st1 = Cd_1, @st2 = Cd_2 
    from [dbo].[TableA]
    WHERE ID = @PractitionerId

    INSERT INTO tableB (ID, Cd) select @PractitionerIdas ID ,* from dbo.Split(' ', @st1)
    INSERT INTO tableB (Id, Cd) select @PractitionerIdas ID,* from dbo.Split(' ', @st2)

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @PractitionerId
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```